# Invalid argument: NodeDef mentions attr 'Tshape' not in Op

Tags: android, python, java-native-interface, tensorflow

I am getting the error `Invalid argument: NodeDef mentions attr 'Tshape' not in Op<name=Reshape; signature=tensor:T, shape:int32 -> output:T; attr=T:type>; NodeDef: Y_GroundTruth = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32](LOut_Add, Y_GroundTruth/shape)` when attempting to load the file on Android using `tensorflow::Status s = session->Create(graph_def);`.

People with similar problems have mentioned that upgrading to Tensorflow 0.9.0rc0 fixed their problems. However, I am already using the most current Tensorflow build in my jni-build.

Could this be a problem with the variables declared when generating the protobuf file?

**Snippet**

```
def reg_perceptron(t, weights, biases):
    t = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(t, weights['h1']), biases['b1']), name = "layer_1")
    t = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.add(tf.matmul(t, weights['h2']), biases['b2']), name = "layer_2")
    t = tf.add(tf.matmul(t, weights['hOut'], name="LOut_MatMul"), biases['bOut'], name="LOut_Add")

    return tf.reshape(t, [-1], name="Y_GroundTruth")

g = tf.Graph()
with g.as_default():
   ...
   rg_weights = {
    'h1': vs.get_variable("weights0", [n_input, n_hidden_1], initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()),
    'h2': vs.get_variable("weights1", [n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2], initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()),
    'hOut': vs.get_variable("weightsOut", [n_hidden_2, 1], initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
    }


    rg_biases = {
    'b1': vs.get_variable("bias0", [n_hidden_1], initializer=init_ops.constant_initializer(bias_start)),
    'b2': vs.get_variable("bias1", [n_hidden_2], initializer=init_ops.constant_initializer(bias_start)),
    'bOut': vs.get_variable("biasOut", [1], initializer=init_ops.constant_initializer(bias_start))
    }

    pred = reg_perceptron(_x, rg_weights, rg_biases)
    ...
...

g_2 = tf.Graph()
with g_2.as_default():
    ...
    rg_weights_2 = {
    'h1': vs.get_variable("weights0", [n_input, n_hidden_1], initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()),
    'h2': vs.get_variable("weights1", [n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2], initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()),
    'hOut': vs.get_variable("weightsOut", [n_hidden_2, 1], initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
    }

    rg_biases_2 = {
    'b1': vs.get_variable("bias0", [n_hidden_1], initializer=init_ops.constant_initializer(bias_start)),
    'b2': vs.get_variable("bias1", [n_hidden_2], initializer=init_ops.constant_initializer(bias_start)),
    'bOut': vs.get_variable("biasOut", [1], initializer=init_ops.constant_initializer(bias_start))
    }

    pred_2 = reg_perceptron(_x_2, rg_weights_2, rg_biases_2)
    ...
```

To stop the post from being too cluttered, I have uploaded my code to generate the .PB-file and my model to create the model on Pastebin.

[PBFileGeneration](http://pastebin.com/6rv1rWV7)

[Model](http://pastebin.com/8DJx1kmL)

Comment: I don't see an obvious reason why it shouldn't work. Did you try running the model on your desktop?

Comment: The model works on Python. I have not tested it on the graph where I create the .PB-file yet though.

Comment: The code I used to test the trained model in the graph used to generate the .PB-file in PBFileGeneration runs without errors.

Comment: OK, maybe it's a bug. If you could cross-post on our [github](https://www.github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues) page, we could track it there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The issue can now be found on [github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5585).